# How to Optmize a multiple if else with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a static class:

```
 public static class ConfigurationDetails
    {
        public static string SharepointServer { get; set; }
        public static string Username { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }
        public static string SharepointDomain { get; set; }
        public static string ServiceLibrary { get; set; }
        public static string SqlServer { get; set; }
        public static string SQLUsername { get; set; }
        public static string SQLPassword { get; set; }
        public static string SQLDomain { get; set; }
    }
```

which needs to be updated from the values of a dictionary . Using if the code is below:

```
var configValues = ReadConfiguration();


 if (configValues.ContainsKey("SharepointServer"))
            {
                ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = configValues["SharepointServer"];

            }
            if (configValues.ContainsKey("ServiceLibrary"))
            {
                ConfigurationDetails.ServiceLibrary = configValues["ServiceLibrary"];

            }
            if (configValues.ContainsKey("Username"))
            {
                ConfigurationDetails.Username = configValues["Username"];

            }
            if (configValues.ContainsKey("Password"))
            {
                ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = configValues["Password"];

            }
```

Now this will do the job but there would be lot of if conditions. I tried with LINQ , but this is closest I got.

```
 configValues.Where(kv => kv.Key == "SharepointServer").ToList().ForEach(kv => ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = kv.Value);
```

and it's not doing any good. Any other ideas please.

Comment: You could extract your if-clause and the resulting assignment into another method, but I don't see how Linq will help here.

Comment: You can create `Dictionary` first, to have sort of *Mapping* between settings and their "names". If names matches - then use Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to populate your static class with config values:

```
var type = typeof(ConfigurationDetails);
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;

foreach(var kvp in configValues)
{        
    var property = type.GetProperty(kvp.Key, flags);
    if (property != null)
       property.SetValue(null, kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is not the right tool here. But you can improve it anyway:

```
string value;
if (configValues.TryGetValue("SharepointServer", out value))
    ConfigurationDetails.SharepointServer = value;
if (configValues.TryGetValue("ServiceLibrary", out value))
    ConfigurationDetails.ServiceLibrary = value;
if (configValues.TryGetValue("Username", out value))
    ConfigurationDetails.Username = value;
if (configValues.TryGetValue("Password", out value))
    ConfigurationDetails.Password = value;
```

This is more concise  and even more efficient (although that is not important in this case).

Comment: As additional improvement, move `if` into a method and just assign value of that method to all. It can set `default` value if specified name not exists (or you can pass initial value as a parameter, so it will be returned back if settings is mising).

Comment: `value` need's to be initialized i guess cuz you are using if condition's!

Comment: @Anirudh no need to initialize it no matter using if or not, the first use of `value` should be in a `out value` form and that will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

What returned type do we have to expect from `ReadConfiguration();` ?

If it will be a list, than your storage with static class members will lead to data loos because only the last values will be stored and earlier ones will be overwritten.

Otherwise, you could do it with reflection by determining the properties of the static class and asuming the properties from Configuration are named the same way and then assign the values that way.